# How do you change the border color of iCheck checkbox to match its surrounding color?

Tags: jquery, icheck

[image]

There are still white borders that can be seen with icheck. Is there any way to make this disappear? I've tried all sorts of things like change the background and border color of the div it's in and what not but it absolutely has no effect.

```
<td>
 {!! Form::checkbox('checkbox_to_approve', '1', null, ['id' => 'checkbox_to_approve_' . $index, 'class' => 'checkbox_to_approve', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'data-work_day_id' => $time_record['work_day_id']]) !!}
 {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($time_record['work_day'])->format('m/d')}}
</td>

$('input[id^=checkbox]').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-naviblue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_flat-naviblue'
});

.icheckbox_flat-naviblue,
.iradio_flat-naviblue {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(naviblue.png) no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Please include some html and css

Comment: There's not much html and css in the code to be honest. I just use the Form::checkbox inside a td tag. Also the program uses bootflat.

Comment: Looks like the background of the checkbox is done by png. If it's png with no transparency then it probably causes this white border and the only solution is to get rid of it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I finally understood what the problem is.